# javascript getElementById() for loop (empty textbox validation)

Tags: javascript

i have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/pmv7W/) that validate against empty textboxes. If there are empty ones, the form will not be able to submit successfully.

However,I cannot seem to get the alert to popup after clicking submit looping through the elements to find if there are any empty boxes to fill in.

any advice/correction on the looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read the [jsfiddle documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GbX8m/2/) you'll find a working version of your code. The (corrected) function:

```
function submitform() {
    var msg = ''
        ,elems = document.getElementById('tasks').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].id && elems[i].id.match(/^t/i) && 
            elems[i].value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'') === '')
        {
            msg += elems[i].id+ ' is empty!\n';
        }
    }
    if (msg.length > 0) {
        alert("one or more of the inputs is/are empty\n"+msg);
        return false
    }
    else alert('we are cool');
    return true;
}
```

A bit more worked out: http://jsfiddle.net/GbX8m/4/

Comment: your code does not execute the submitform() function from the button instead you replace it with a onclick="return false". So how am i suppose to trigger the function?

Comment: @pivotal developer: the function runs onload. In http://jsfiddle.net/GbX8m/2/ you can use the submit button too.

Comment: @ Kooilnc is it the same if i trigger the function at submit button with onclick="submitform()" instead of the form's onsubmit="submitform()"  ?

Comment: @pivotal developer: it can have the same effect (alerting a message), but isn't the same. If you use onsubmit, the return value of [submitform] 'decides' if the form gets submitted. If you use onclick on the submit button, you'll have to submit the form programmatically from within the [submitform] function.

Comment: @Kooilnc Okie, thanks for clarifying. I also do not really understand the regular expressions you are using. Tried to look online but there's minimal information. what if i want to match id=task and what does this replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'') means? is it to remove spaces?

Comment: @pivotal developer`: /^\s+|\s+$/ searches spaces at the beginning and ending of a string, these are replaced with nothing (''). So, if somebody fills a text input with spaces only, that's regarded as no input at all. For matching id's from elements: every element needs a unique id, that's why I numbered the id's of the text input elements. If you call them task1/task2 etc the match would be /^task/i (i stands for 'case insensitive', ^ for 'from the start')

Comment: @Kooilnc For the unique id, i'm afraid i cannot use it this way because it will affect my codes. I need something that is like a class and applicable across all is it possible?

Comment: @Kooilnc Also, if my 'input' is not a direct children of say 'tasks' will i be able to retrieve it? In your example, 'Tasks' is a direct parent of 'input'. My codes are probably stuck because the inputs are nested within label and div. Correct me if i am wrong about that.

Comment: @pivotal developer: well, you could give the text input elements a classname: class="task" and check that in the loop. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GbX8m/5/

Comment: @Kooilnc Thanks, the code works now. But i am curious, i havent come across something like that before --> var mv = emptyels === 1 ? ['one','is'] : ['some','are']; Could you explain the geez of the code?

Comment: @pivotal developer: check the comment in the updated fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/GbX8m/6/

Answer (score 2):

Move your onSubmit into the  tag instead of the Submit button, for one... it's not firing the event at the proper time. It should be like:

```
<form action="whatever" onSubmit="return submitform();">
```

Also change the last line of the function,

```
else document.forms[0].submit();
```

to

```
return true;
```

This should solve the problem of it not running properly, and not intercepting the submission of the form.

Also, you shouldn't have multiple items with the same ID. It's not valid HTML and can cause problems with some browsers *cough*IE*cough*, though you'd probably get away with it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not following dom rules. ID should be uniquer for each element. You should have unique id. Read xhtml guidelines.
2. document.getElementById will return one element not array. If you want to apply on group use function which apply on group like  document.getElementsByClassName.
3. form tab should have action . if you want it to on same page use. action="#"
4. Fire submit form on form submit not button click      and submitform should return true of false depending on if form is valid or not.
5. If that is for education purpose then good. Otherwise use framework like jquery those have many function which will reduce your work.